# Taking user input and check if each word is in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I am building a language translator for an assignment.

There are two dictionaries, one for words and one for phrases

It takes a word in English and provides the equivalent word in Aafrikaans
It can also take a small phrase in English and provide the equivalent phrase in Aafrikaans

To go to the next level, I also want to take the users input and then check against these two dictionaries to see if they first match the phrase dictionary, second check the word dictionary, and if none match, then search for the individual words in the word dictionary and provide a literal translation

Example would be - I love you - translates to ek het jou lief

But if the user typed in just love you - I would want it to match the word dictionary and say liefde jy

I thought the way to do it would be to take the input and split the input into a list and then take that list and search for each word sequentially in each dictionary - but for the life of me i cant see how i can do that in a loop. My code is below - the splitword throws a hash error and i cant see how i would do this - is there a better way or some other way i should do this - the rest works

```
i2w = {'hello': 'hallo', 'love': 'liefde', 'you': 'jy', 'I': 'ek', 'are': 'is', 'a': 'a', 'man': 'man', 'woman': 'vrou', 'how': 'hoe', 'the': 'die', 'best': 'beste', 'smell': 'reuk', 'nice': 'lekker'}
i2p = {'i love you': 'ek het jou lief', 'you are welcome': 'jy is welkom', 'life is good': 'die lewe is goed'}

question = input("Please enter the word or phrase you would like translated from Engish to Aafrikaans?:  ").lower()
splitquestion = question.split ()

while question != "finished":
    if question in i2p:
        print("The Aafrikaans translation is ",i2p.get(question))
        break   
    elif question in i2w:
        print("The Aafrikaans translation is ",i2w.get(question))
        break 
    elif splitquestion in i2w:
        print("The Aafrikaans translation is ",i2w.get(splitquestion))
        break 
    else:
        question = input("Sorry this specific word or phrase is not in the dictionary, be mindful of word order or grammar, Please enter what word or phrase you would like translated from Engish to Aafrikaans?:  ").lower()
print ("\nThanks for using the translator tool!")
```

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
words = {'hello': 'hallo', 'love': 'liefde', 'you': 'jy', 'I': 'ek', 'are': 'is', 'a': 'a', 'man': 'man', 'woman': 'vrou', 'how': 'hoe', 'the': 'die', 'best': 'beste', 'smell': 'reuk', 'nice': 'lekker'}
phrases = {'i love you': 'ek het jou lief', 'you are welcome': 'jy is welkom', 'life is good': 'die lewe is goed'}

inputPhrase = input('Please enter the word or phrase you would like translated from Engish to Aafrikaans?:  ').lower()

# Take a string, input, return the phrase or None if it doesn't exist.
def translate(input):
  outputPhrase = ''
  if inputPhrase in phrases:
    outputPhrase += phrases.get(inputPhrase)
    return outputPhrase
  else:
    splitInput = inputPhrase.split()
    for word in splitInput:
      if word in words:
        outputPhrase += f' {words.get(word)}'
      # This would return None if not all words are in the dictionary.
      else:
        return None
    return outputPhrase

translated = translate(inputPhrase)
while not translated:
  inputPhrase = input('Sorry this specific word or phrase is not in the dictionary, be mindful of '
                   'word order or grammar, ' +
                   'Please enter what word or phrase you would like translated from Engish to Aafrikaans?:  ').lower()
  translated = translate(inputPhrase)

print(f'The Aafrikaans translation is {translated}.')
print ('\nThanks for using the translator tool!')
```

I find this implementation a little cleaner with the use of a function. The most important part is in the function's `else` block. It will split the phrase at whitespace, then iterate through every word. If one word isn't in the dictionary, it will return None for the whole thing. This can be easily changed by changing the `else` to something like

```
outputPhrase += ''
```

Comment: Hi Sean - thanks for this answer, I added it to my code and found that when it matches a phrase perfectly - for instance if I type "i love you' it translates to 'ek het jou lief'. However it does not seem to match single words - so if i type 'love' it tells me the word does not exist and to enter another word. If i type 'love you' it doesn't match anything and tells me to enter another word. Something isn't quite right in the word section - trying to troubleshoot

Comment: @DNSFishing Hey! Sorry for the bugs. I changed some things before posting, and was in a rush so I didn't test them. I'm sure you've figured it out by now, but it should be working. I forgot to reset `translate` in the while loops and forgot to return from the else loop. The post has been edited with the correct code.

Comment: Thanks Sean - this works a treat - I will now go back and play with the code to learn a little more and understand. My issue being new to programming python is not what i want to do or even what i might need to do conceptually with the code to get there, its the "right way or easiest way" to get there, to get to know "what should be" done and in what order. like for some reason I want to try and build it all into one loop - but i get the feel its rather small incremental test steps is the better way - how did you come to learn this

Comment: Weird little easter egg Sean - So when I type "i love woman" - all these words exist in the word dictionary - it seem to error same if i type "i love best" it seems to think it matches the phrase dictionary perhaps?

Comment: I found the issue - i had the I in the dictionary as a capital and for some reason it didn't like that

Comment: I think the style of your code will just come with time. I've only been working in the industry for a year, and I've learned more in this year than I learned in school. But I had to struggle through school first to get here. I'm by no means the best, but stick with it and you'll get better. What you had is already impressive!


Oh yeah that makes sense because `'i' != 'I'`. You could always check both sides with the `.toLower()` method to make them the same, but in this specific scenario, it's probably easiest to just make the i in the dictionary lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Taking user input and check if each word is in a dictionary can be done as follows:

```
question = input()
splitquestion = question.split()
for word in splitquestion:
    if word in iw2:
       # do something
```

The `question` variable is a string and after using the `split` method you get a list of strings (the words from the original question). [Here's more info about the split method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp).
You might also want to refresh your knowledge on [iterating over lists in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_loop.asp).

Comment: Thank you dominik-air, I will have a go and see if i can get this to work!

Comment: Hi dominik-air, when i tried to apply this code, if i type a single word ie 'love' it translates no issue. If i type "love you' then i get two lines with the output 'none'. I have tried to mess around with key and value to see if that makes a difference, it just doesn't seem to be able to identify the individual words exist in the dictionary

Comment: #update - I got this code to work - now i need to build it back into the sequence to get all 3 scenarios working

Comment: @DNSFishing if I were you I would first check if the whole phrase is in the `i2p` dictionary and if so just return or print out the key's value, otherwise run the for loop I've provided with some modifications, so the individual words can be translated with the `i2w` dictionary

Comment: Thanks dominik-air, I will take your advice and build this into the code alongside Seans example below and will try and get both working so i can learn from them both and understand what works well and what i should be doing - thankyou for your help.

Comment: for the life of me dominik-air - I cannot get it to work this way - test its in the phrase dictionary fine, then when i check the word dictionary - i can even get that fine - i can even get it to ask for the input again from the user if the dictionary doesn't exist - but then how to get it to go back to the top of the code to start again if it doesn't exist - cannot get that to work. looked at goto commands looked at trying to nest the for loop inside a while loop - that causes lots of issues, every time i think I've solved it it has an issue - i must be stupid!

Comment: @DNSFishing maybe ask another question with the code you're struggling with right now so people will directly see it?